# How to do "object projection" filter in JMESpath, or how to filter a list?

Tags: jmespath

Given the following JSON:

```
{
  "apps": {
    "foo": {
      "version": "1"
    },
    "bar": {
      "version": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to get the number of apps which have a version 2. 
An object projection

```
apps.*.version
```

gives a list,

```
[
  "1",
  "2"
]
```

but how to filter that list after that?
I did not find any examples for that in the tutorial (since there is not property to filter against like `[?version!='']`, although it seems to be a quite basic use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, using this syntax it is possible to do that.

```
apps.*.version | [?@=='2']
```

Comment: I think there should be a dot before the star, no?  `jmespath.search("apps.*.version | [?@=='2']", data)`

Comment: @MaxMurphy: thank you, I have omitted the dot. edited